# how does amazon s3 virtual style path for buckets work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello everyone i am just trying out my hands at amazon web services and s3 storage service specially but i am having difficulty in understanding that how does virtual style path for buckets work i.e. how are they resolved at DNS level and how does my browser knows that request must be sent to amazon s3 servers. Does amazon create a sub-domain for every bucket and if not how does this works. For e.g. suppose i have a bucket named mycoolbucket and now i want to perform actions on it via aws s3 rest api so i use virtual style based path which will be something like mycoolbucket.s3.amazonaws.com so how shall my browser know where to send the request to? Forgive me if it seems a bit naive but i really want to know the working behind this because as far as i can guess the s3.amazonaws.com is already a sub-domain of amazonaws.com right?

Comment: `but i really want to know the working behind this because as far as i can guess the s3.amazonaws.com is already a sub-domain of amazonaws.com right?` - right. Bucket names must be globally unique because they have an associated DNS record as you allude to.

Comment: @arco444 can you kindly elaborate the part about associated DNS record?does creating a s3-bucket also creates a sub-domain of same name automatically?

Comment: It will at least create some sort of virtual routing for the name, it looks like s3 is configured to respond with a CNAME record for all requests to s3.amazonaws.com. Valid bucket names will be handled by whatever web services live behind the DNS addresses. Invalid names return an error to that effect